# Why isn't the display: flex property being inherited to child divs?

Tags: html, css, inheritance, flexbox

I'm learning how to use flexbox, and I cannot get my child divs to inherit the display:flex property.

I have tried using Chrome and Firefox, I am seeing the same issue in both browsers. The only way I can get the .menu class to inherit the property is by explicitly including 'display: inherit' in the .menu class, even though I set 'display: flex' in the parent ".menu-container" class.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.menu-container {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #5995DA;  /* Blue */
  padding: 20px 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.menu {
  display: inherit; /* Why do I need this? I shouldn't, right? */
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  width: 900px;
}
```

```html
    <div class='menu-container'>
      <div class='menu'>
        <div class='date'>Aug 14, 2016</div>
        <div class='signup'>Sign Up</div>
        <div class='login'>Login</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: because display is defined to not be inherited. As simple as that

Answer (score 3):

`display: flex` is only used for the specific class. Children are treated separately as flex-items.

[Flexbox Explanations](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) if you are interested.